# Android Base64 to Image Conversion different encodings?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, base64

I am trying to convert a Base64 String / Byte Array to an Image, however it is not working.

I have existing drawables that I am encoding and decoding and that works fine.

So I am thinking that the encoding that I am using is incorrect.

I am logging the `base64` like this:

`Log.e("TAG", content)`

Base64 from Database (Straight image not converted to drawable, doesn't work), not formatted at all:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEBLAEsAAD/4QolRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAYgEbAAUAAAABAAAAagEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAUAAAAcgEyAAIAAAAUAAAAhodpAAQAAAABAAAAnAAAAMgAAAEsAAAAAQAAASwAAAABQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIDcuMAAyMDE1OjA0OjEyIDIwOjU5OjAxAAAAAAOgAQADAAAAAf//AACgAgAEAAAAAQAABNqgAwAEAAAAAQAACKAAAAAAAAAABgEDAAMAAAABAAYAAAEaAAUAAAABAAABFgEbAAUAAAABAAABHgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAIBAAQAAAABAAABJgICAAQAAAABAAAI9wAAAAAAAABIAAAAAQAAAEgAAAAB/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/7QAMQWRvYmVfQ00AAf/uAA5BZG9iZQBkgAAAAAH/2wCEAAwICAgJCAwJCQwRCwoLERUPDAwPFRgTExUTExgRDAwMDAwMEQwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwBDQsLDQ4NEA4OEBQODg4UFA4ODg4UEQwMDAwMEREMDAwMDAwRDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDP/AABEIAIAASAMBIgACEQEDEQH/3QAEAAX/xAE/AAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAADAAECBAUGBwgJCgsBAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAEAAgMEBQYHCAkKCxAAAQQBAwIEAgUHBggFAwwzAQACEQMEIRIxBUFRYRMicYEyBhSRobFCIyQVUsFiMzRygtFDByWSU/Dh8WNzNRaisoMmRJNUZEXCo3Q2F9JV4mXys4TD03Xj80YnlKSFtJXE1OT0pbXF1eX1VmZ2hpamtsbW5vY3R1dnd4eXp7fH1+f3EQACAgECBAQDBAUGBwcGBTUBAAIRAyExEgRBUWFxIhMFMoGRFKGxQiPBUtHwMyRi4XKCkkNTFWNzNPElBhaisoMHJjXC0kSTVKMXZEVVNnRl4vKzhMPTdePzRpSkhbSVxNTk9KW1xdXl9VZmdoaWprbG1ub2JzdHV2d3h5ent8f/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/APVUkkklKSSQrrdjZAnUADjU+f7v7ySkqSz25t1T7G5EP2QfYCCGkT9F/wBPYrofIBEEHghGlM0kOy+qpm+w7GjST4nsFHGy8bKa52O8PDHbH6EEGA73NdDvc1zXs/fZ70FJkkkklP8A/9D1G15a0xz2nQLOv6lkYwJyGBjJAa+CQSTDd213tV3Ia9zXCsxYIcz+sPc0f1XfRVW66jIoJta11TtCx5iZ8j+cxFSXDynXt/SNa138kyNRuHP0faiW621iToHO/wCpbP8AmuesPeMSwfZbCcd72ito3ENgbXA2OG32u99a0MTOdkurcWgX1TXa0cEPb6tV1f8AIt9H+x+kr/wSKmGaC3OaGw2WAbzqBB9rQ35bkduTVi4DbHS4NPp1tn3OO4tYwf6/o61W6i6v7ZS4nlntb4ul3b+Q1UMt9khjnEVUFwrBkOLyS665un5vrNx97/3LP9IkhFY7L6r1FtAf7X+0lwgCsT9ofU0bnM/cr3/T/wAMuhoqZRlAVMa1jqAz29hU7bU3+V7bnKj0TCZj47crIj1rW7awORWfotj/AIT6a0KXGy57jqax6ZcONxO+xg/e9L9Ezd++gltpJhwkgp//0fUnjVZ4oqdmXW605Ahge0D6H0mfSDt3q/v/AMj0/wDArRfws/IFr7t9TvTfSSwtgkOaYd7/APq2OrY/YiFM/WtZpe0WMg7rauCP5dR/77vVG3Cqptbm4xG0RXbtkj0zHpv/AOs/ns/0atvzH0iMmp4YP8K1hsbH736Hc/b/ANbQbiykbq3TjXaPGoDS72+o3/gnfn7UVNO3MYMs3OIjHqe927wYN+1/9Z6Bj4tz8qup0w1oOTadNQf0lbtfpX2+q/2f4FUb3wy5uRue1mloI1tIdQ303R/hNw/7d/4NbeK9za2NDWuy3zvcR7Q9x1b+/b6Vft/qbPoJKdC6/UY9BLbHjVzRqxn7/u9u923bRv8A+M/m61Fl3oVtYGgCIqpbqSPzfc47v61tiqVuaxxpxwbsi07nuJ7Hmy1/8qP/AEVSj11Mpef8Nk2/TdoTp+a1v5jGfvvSU6NT22MD26tIkJKNLSxjWHkCDCSHVT//0vVDwq2RU4kWV6n84AkGP3mfylaUDoYRCmmy1rjDSZafcNYn+Vu97HKpdTjB5bWPTc76XokEHxa+kjb/AOBrUfVU9257AXDh0a/530lE42O4e5gImYPHz/eRU8ycZjcqw1WNa1r6jZYfo+m17G32tf8AQbbiX+m//BfQ/Ser+serdc9l9r68OfsjWt/Tsl0/usrdFjtv+E9TZ6XqfpPUWh1GhraW5FbROMPo8NdUYF1Tvzdmz3ImDjspxWY419EubPB53Tp++135qCmpViekxtLG2MYdXOaAJP7u6x/us/4W5HoLaZbXW5rifc10ST2n3b3f2FaNFJ5YD8lJtdbTLWgHxRUybOk6HuEk4GqSCn//0/VUC61lTTY8w0fj5BGcYCoZpb6tQe31Kx9JhIgh59L6Lvp+7YzZ/wAJYiFIxm5W+x5aw11gOfTqHsaR7XOt+g59n0vT2K9XYyxgfW4OY7UEKjS/dl5AaTa1vpvYwzAAbLX3Od7/AGvb+7v3/wDQL0wPFDg926Hkg8fSayw/9N3uSU2XvYxpc8w3g9+TtDY/O3SqQyshrga21sp2t9KmHFxadwafUq3sb7Gfm12MUs2+kWek6xoe1jnBkgHc4FjHncW/RZ6irDLxPt1r2X1tp9FkOGjvp2uNLf3fc79J/hNn/bqSnTbdW6oXSQwidRqNdu0t/f3e3aqTs/JN4DWsrr2OeGv9znBpbLvYfZs/kesoOux2Yb2+qxzGXDbuMtc5rW3vZPu3b7NyGczEGc1osZ6TWWezTbusfU5oN/8AN+j7H2+3/rn+jSU6tFnqMa8jaTMiQYI0PuH0kkDpljbKXbbG2lj3BxboNdW+yXbPakkp/9T1N/CodRAb6VrjFO707uAQ1/trsr3f4Rlu3/rdj1ff9FUcptt9ZrBLHifaW72OkRtfp+mrdu/fqRCkAA+0ZYcWvFjqtANrXzWTuu/er2N32f6T0/8Arat4VQqxmgAtDiXNaeQ0/Qn/AK3s3LJrc+zKyMOT9oLQ2HnUN907ne12z030evd/OWf9fWti031tHrWiwxqQOT4ztbtZ+5W1JTY1T6+acN8VJK1MIcnh3ipJJWpYCEk6SCn/1fVOdEOxr9jg0kOIO0iJntG8Ob/nNRUkrU49HQqhc/KtayvItO55rAe6T45OU2yx3H+Drx1rNbHy4UkkbUpJJJBSkkkklKSSSSU//9b1VJJJJSkkkklKSSSSUpJJJJSkkkklP//Z/+0OtFBob3Rvc2hvcCAzLjAAOEJJTQQlAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADhCSU0D7QAAAAAAEAEsAAAAAQACASwAAAABAAI4QklNBCYAAAAAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAP4AAADhCSU0EDQAAAAAABAAAAHg4QklNBBkAAAAAAAQAAAAeOEJJTQPzAAAAAAAJAAAAAAAAAAABADhCSU0ECgAAAAAAAQAAOEJJTScQAAAAAAAKAAEAAAAAAAAAAjhCSU0D9QAAAAAASAAvZmYAAQBsZmYABgAAAAAAAQAvZmYAAQChmZoABgAAAAAAAQAyAAAAAQBaAAAABgAAAAAAAQA1AAAAAQAtAAAABgAAAAAAAThCSU0D+AAAAAAAcAAA/////////////////////////////wPoAAAAAP////////////////////////////8D6AAAAAD/////////////////////////////A+gAAAAA/////////////////////////////wPoAAA4QklNBAgAAAAAABAAAAABAAACQAAAAkAAAAAAOEJJTQQeAA
```

Base64 from existing drawable (Does work), it is formatted well:

```
 /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
    AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
    AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAPUAicDASIA
    AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
    AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
    ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
    p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
    AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
    BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
    U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
    uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD+/iii
    igAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKK
    ACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA
    KKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAo
    oooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACii
    igAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKK
    ACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA
    KKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAo
    oooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACii
    igAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKK
    ACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKbuX1/n7j+n8vXJ
    dQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFF
    ABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFJuUcZ6exoAWig
    c9P89f8A4k/56lABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQBXjhMSFAdw45OM8Fvf3GfbaM
    8NViiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAoooo
    AKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKTIAJ9P/svf/Z/UdeaRjhWPp/8AFEdz6Kf/ANfJg3Mc
    kDPvkc9R6nHT+fcEmW2r2Te1tHbeS7+Sduz31AnDA+31wO+P734/SlyPUfmP8aqFyCQVYYJAODg4
    OP7vGQCR17jORynmgdePTknP38AYB5Ozp1GRwTUpztrFvpez8/6+7zJ50m1rp6ea7+X563TbtlgP
    f6Y9SP73tn6EetJvHv8AkP8A4qq6SBhyrdccbs5xnoUwOMYLMBzjqMl4KE4O4Htypz1B754xzx1z
    ycElrn8vn6vz8vW1ur1paq/p/wC3eb/l/FavUnB3DI/zyw/9l9e475paamNvGce/X7z/ANc/hjuG
    p1Uttd7L/wBuv/7b/VwCiiimAU0sB1z9fxYev+zk+xHPWgnH09fzx+ePX154OcXWNc07RrO4vL+d
    YoYI2eU5B2KqyuTt6sxRSVjGXc4RQWHIBsGRQCcMcduM45GfvdDj1z19CSwyEj5c84x+Z6nPHTjn
    1z0weT8Laxe+ILR9SltEttOuSWsCz/vbuAE7Jwu1WjV93CMu4HdkkAE9ake1cLgDHIPJ+8+ece3P
    vj05AJVztGeuF/P95nqT6D9OTjlaAMDH0H5bv8f5ehyUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUU
    AFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQA
    UUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAVF5mFJ4znAHb+Lrz/s+vc9dpzLUEtvFNFJDJuKSo0bgH
    BKsrKwBAyMhjyORnOcigDzfxT8U/CnhqK7S41bTZLi2XEsK31vv3h2BhUGUfv/7sJO9i2Bkrz4rr
    3xx1u5hNt4f0fWrW4mki+zXFxpuYpYnkJLwW7RfaJECgxNNGJI1nWTLBVZq9rk+D3w0aZ7yTwpp0
    t3uMguZlkeUSlnxLuZyPMGcq5G4EjkkV4545/Z0Outc3Phfxhqeiy7E8rTtRiGpaGrCR2UrbAxSY
    D/vdpkbErFiRuNaUp0otqa1umpPZJSl59dX8mnvrnJSezdrbL/E+jWvS2736HzNr/iL4/eItSvYJ
    fHtz4TsZJGaFn0LXbaMQy5aIC5MaxvOYyGdIyU4YgYU153ceAP2g33XFj+0JAXaUCMXOtzacyq3m
    hT/xMJowWfIwUyinHmHlawvil4a/aJ+C+o3Gtaz4YuvEHh6S6SxPjbwz5uq2dlaqJpxLP4K0y4v9
    XVGEcZQQWcrruSEEAuTyulftjQ+H9Sk0W5l0jXppbN7mdFlVPstrG8SQvdxTRLNaeYZXPl3CJJuR
    12gxyV3QdGV4xlpo76a39NNOut/Ns5JtqTTlJNKNtbXXvedk1ZPXq1qndv0TTNN/a48LatDJbfFy
    x1ghWndbn4geDpoGCKwVJLO/vlMyMsatz+7+dgp80PXungv48ftN2U4tPEHw40/xnAqRvJqeg6np
    N7OQ1xMriOPRbmeMssaqFVBgMMMdwcn58b9pLw9qumC6OoaUst5G8lrDo1st06M/mRtA9xBHKUcP
    CT5LcqCHwVkzXMWHxo0kvJPqVjcraSiF5bkzXenXBMMaxEySSGBCAVO1VG9lKnDcsadGld3im+ru
    9d/Pz/q7CM5KNlJpaaP/ALe7+i+9dbt/ojpv7WGhWM8Fj8QvBHjf4fzTym2ivNc8NaumlPdJvMif
    bTbhFiAV3W4c+WygKGLtz9C+HfHXhfxZbm58OeING1eIfK32DULe5eKQb90M6wzOYpV2NlG5+Uty
    GBr8jrH9orwjenVxo914otFgjitbB4bm6nguXSeR9QVDfafcQm3jvP8Aj32/dg8uMSMnzVy/in4v
    aDaxWKaD408T6j4zmuUu9L0jTobaGz/ta5JS0ju78taafbQyusMcrTXTLGmXdlVHY8sqEXdRlbVa
    6vq11fl876u1m+iMpWV3fSP/ALf+fKr9++9/3BE7HbwMEgAgMQTk9CMjkDIzx15JHMnmH2/X/H/P
    qa/J34f/ALTXjPwjPe2XinxNZ3s2n2FhqWspf3cB03Srq4keO50OW8aYNNPbBUne40
```

**Update**: How am I encoding to the DB?

I am using `php` to encode and save into a `blob` column. The image is saved in the `$row['Image']` column as the binary content of the Image:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
      $blob = $row['Image'];
      $id = $row['ID'];

      $base64 = base64_encode($blob);
      echo $base64;

      $mysql = "UPDATE Images SET Image = '" . $base64 . "' WHERE ID     = " . $id . ";";
      $q = mysql_query($mysql);
  }
```

Comment: I could decode the unformatted base64 string, but  couldn't obtain a bitmap image with `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgData, 0, imgData.length);` as it returns `null`. Could it be possible that you are trying to decode an unsupported image format? Can you detail the original file meta-data?

Comment: Same thing here. To get the image I just write the `Image` field contents to a file and put `.jpg` on the end. It is `JPEG image (image/jpeg)`

Comment: @Markus Aha, I have to write contents to a `.jpg` and then convert it to a drawable and then convert that to `base64` and then write it back to the db. What does that mean? Why does this have to happen?

Comment: Can you open the .jpg file? I have decoded the base64 stream in android then I saved it to a file and pulled it out of the device to my pc. Then I tried to open it on my pc but it doesn't display. Probably the source image is broken - i am looking into troubleshooting a binary image now.